# Heroku Postgres: how to SET session_replication_role = replica;

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have tried to change session_replication_role to 'replica' with TablePlus but I get permission denied when I try to do it.

Is there any other way to do this with Heroku Postgres? I am trying to do a database migration but for some reason I don't have permissions to change this value.

Thanks!

Comment: Heroku Postgres, being a managed service, doesn't grant you superuser permissions or access, so you don't break things. You'll likely need to use their backup functionality or [pg:copy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases).

Comment: Does it mean in order to change the session replication role, I would need to run it on a backup database?

Comment: It means you cannot change `session_replication_role` on Heroku, period.